# Find all \$k\$-smooth pairs

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

#### Introduction

In number theory, we say a number is \$k\$-smooth when its prime factors are all at most \$k\$. For example, 2940 is 7-smooth because \$2940=2^2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7^2\$.

Here, we define a \$k\$-smooth pair as two consecutive integers which both are \$k\$-smooth. An example of 7-smooth pair will be \$(4374,4375)\$ because \$4374=2\cdot3^7\$ and \$4375=5^4\cdot7\$. **Fun fact: This is actually the largest 7-smooth pair**.

Størmer proved in 1897 that [for every \$k\$, there are only finitely many \$k\$-smooth pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem), and this fact is known as **Størmer's Theorem**.

#### Challenge

Your task is to write a program or function that, given a prime number input \$k\$, outputs or returns all \$k\$-smooth pairs without duplicate (order within the pair does not matter) in any order you want.

Please be noted that for prime numbers \$p\$ and \$q\$, assuming \$p<q\$, all \$p\$-smooth pairs are also \$q\$-smooth pairs.

#### Sample I/O

```
Input: 2
Output: (1, 2)

Input: 3
Output: (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (8, 9)

Input: 5
Output: (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (8, 9), (9, 10), (15, 16), (24, 25), (80, 81)

Input: 7
Output: (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10), (14, 15),
        (15, 16), (20, 21), (24, 25), (27, 28), (35, 36), (48, 49), (49, 50), (63, 64),
        (80, 81), (125, 126), (224, 225), (2400, 2401), (4374, 4375)
```

#### Restriction

The program or function should theoretically terminate in finite time for all inputs. Standard loopholes are disallowed by default.

#### Winning Criteria

As this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, shortest valid submission for each language wins.

Comment: Could you please add test cases for 2, 3, and 5?

Comment: @JonathanAllan 2-, 3- and 5- smooth pairs are included in the 7-smooth pairs, but I will add the cases for clarity

Comment: Is having `(1, 2)` part of the output mandatory?..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, all outputs should contain the `(1, 2)` pair.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>234</s>  232 bytes

Finds the solutions by solving Pell equations of the form \$x^2-2qy^2=1\$, where \$q\$ is a \$P\$-smooth square free number.

This is an implementation of [Derrick Henry Lehmer's procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem#The_procedure), derived from Størmer's original procedure.

Returns an object whose keys and values describe the \$P\$-smooth pairs.

```javascript
P=>[...Array(P**P)].map((_,n)=>(s=(n,i=0,k=2)=>k>P?n<2:n%k?s(n,i,k+1):s(n/k,i,k+i))(n,1)&&(_=>{for(x=1;(y=((++x*x-1)/n)**.5)%1;);(h=(x,y)=>k--&&h(X*x+n*Y*y,X*y+Y*x,x&s(x=~-x/2)&s(x+1)?r[x]=x+1:0))(X=x,Y=y,k=P<5?3:-~P/2)})(),r={})&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5Bb4JAEIXv/RV7qGRmWVbBmCbgQHrofY8aQ5RYrRa7mKVplhD863Ts0d7e@97kzfusfqp2787X78g274fxSKOhfKO1fnWu6sBIabDUX9UVYKssUg4tgVVnmqmaEvZ1bgq7TFI7qYv2nqg6jDFlOa3/zBmRcYxBAFvK@2PjwFOcQUcAYeilj2KcWpRSL3ASZ5jBicCr7t4dRUFwgpX0oZVr2amV7MK19MoHLZfcIj9N8C75Y@E2viRW6YwfrsirNXW80SwXxTyNboZPBwRUjvqBx7gx2yRKzJVYKPFSat71Vu1PYATlon8SYt/Ytrkc9KX5gB1T8dybYYfZQ3QEg/8ggwHHXw)

#### How?

The helper function \$s\$ tests whether a given integer \$n\$ is a \$P\$-smooth number when it's called with \$i=0\$, or a square free<sup>1</sup> \$P\$-smooth number when it's called with \$i=1\$.

```javascript
s = (
  n,
  i = 0,
  k = 2
) =>
  k > P ?
    n < 2
  :
    n % k ?
      s(n, i, k + 1)
    :
      s(n / k, i, k + i)
```

We look for all square free<sup>1</sup> \$P\$-smooth numbers in \$[1..P^P-1]\$, where \$P^P\$ is used as an upper bound for \$P!\$.

```javascript
P=>[...Array(P ** P)].map((_, n) => s(n, 1) && (...))
```

For each number \$n\$ found above, we look for the fundamental solution of the Pell equation \$x^2-ny^2=1\$:

```javascript
(_ => {
  for(x = 1; (y = ((++x * x - 1) / n) ** .5) % 1;);
  ...
})()
```

(the above code is the non-recursive version of [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183301/58563) to [this other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/183298/58563))

Once the fundamental solution \$(x_1,y_1)\$ has been found, we compute the solutions \$(x_k,y_k)\$ with \$k\le max(3,(P+1)/2)\$, using the recurrence relations:

$$x_{k+1}=x_1x_k+ny_1y_k\\
y_{k+1}=x_1y_k+y_1x_k
$$

For each \$x_k\$, we test whether \$x_k\$ is odd and both \$(x_k-1)/2\$ and \$(x_k+1)/2\$ are \$P\$-smooth. If so, we store them in the object \$r\$.

```javascript
( h = (x, y) =>
  k-- &&
  h(
    X * x + n * Y * y,
    X * y + Y * x,
    x &
    s(x = ~-x / 2) &
    s(x + 1) ?
      r[x] = x + 1
    :
      0
  )
)(X = x, Y = y, k = P < 5 ? 3 : -~P / 2)
```

---

*<sup>1: Because it does not test the primality of the divisors, the function \$s\$ will actually be truthy for some non-square free numbers, even when it's called with \$i=1\$. The idea is to filter out most of them so that not too many useless Pell equations are solved.</sup>*

Comment: Hi Arnauld! I just couldn't wrap my head around these two: `x = ~-x / 2` and `-~P / 2`.Are these some kind of rounding...

Comment: @rv7 `~x` is a bitwise NOT, which computes `-(x+1)`. Therefore, `~-x` is `-(-x+1)` = `x-1` and `-~x` is `-(-(x+1))` = `x+1`. Like all bitwise operations in JS, only the 32-bit integer part is taken into account. So the they can indeed be used for rounding. But both \$x\$ and \$P\$ already are integers here.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
4*ÆfṀ<ɗƇ‘rƝLÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//NCrDhmbhuYA8yZfGh@KAmHLGnUzDkOG5gv///zc)

Checks for pairs up to \$4^k\$ which is inefficient for larger \$k\$ but should ensure none are missed.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving 1 byte!

#### Explanation

```
4*ÆfṀ<ɗƇ‘rƝLÐṂ  | Monadic link, input k

4*              | 4**k, call this n
      ɗƇ        | For each number from 1..n filter those where:
  Æf            |   - Prime factors
    Ṁ           |   - Maximum
     <  ‘       |   - Less than k+1
         rƝ     | Inclusive range between neighbouring values
           LÐṂ  | Keep only those of minimum length (i.e. adjacent values)
```

Comment: Are you sure that \$4^k\$ will always be large enough? In my solution, I used \$k!^2\$ but JonathanAllan was not sure that it would always be large enough. If  \$4^k\$ does always work, I would be curious to hear an explanation.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony I looked at the first 20 terms of A117581 in OEIS and tried various functions of k. Using \$4^k\$ is big enough for small k, and seems to rapidly exceed the value of A117581 as k increases. However, I don’t have a deductive proof.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was thinking similarly, but more broadly: "factorial gets pretty high quickly, it's probably big enough." (turns out it wasn't unless I squared it). Congrats on the shorter and more efficient golf, you have my upvote.

Comment: Note (from https://oeis.org/A002072) "a(n) < 10^n/n except for n=4. (Conjectured, from experimental data.) - M. F. Hasler, Jan 16 2015". I think we have to stick with the weak bound of Lehmer in https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456 (theorem 7) unless we can prove otherwise.

Comment: ...there's an open question over on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2147756/227125) asking exactly this too!

Comment: `f’$ż‘$` can be golfed to `rƝLÐṂ`

Comment: @JonathanAllan It’s worth noting that my current method uses \$4^k\$, and since k is always >= 2n where k is the n’th prime, this will be a weaker bound than Hasler’s. Thanks for the golf!

Comment: @PeterTaylor that’s for the number of pairs, not the maximum number. The problem is knowing a bound on the maximum number of pairs doesn’t let you stop searching

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
°Lü‚ʒfà@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Aafw3seNcw6NSnt8AKH//@NAQ)

Explanation:

```
°            # 10 ** the input
 Lü‚         # list of pairs up to that number
    ʒ        # filtered by...
     fà      # the greatest prime factor (of either element of the pair)...
       @     # is <= the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>118</s> 107 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to nimi

```hs
q 1=[1]
q n=(:)<*>q.div n$[x|x<-[2..n],mod n x==0]!!0
f k|let r=all(<=k).q=[(n,n+1)|n<-[1..4^k],r n,r(n+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwGIDhu7/iEzpstYazIgjXL6hTx7FioKJsfrpp5cH/vuz0wgNvY0ZbORejByGV0IkHlORCi@3V87L9AG7UvMzFXuWco2ZdXwLCLGWm0zRLarCLqyYI0jhHCmkp91IRZLgTdMF1E5wfn1azAMgC@bOOnWkRJHRmuL@ADO/pMYUbAoex6b9ragpKsJwd2ImddfwB)

- `q n` calculates a list of all prime factors of `n`
- `f k` generates a list of \$k\$-smooth pairs for a given k by filtering a list of all pairs

Comment: You can loop through `[2..n]` within `p` and inline it into `q`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBC4IwGIDhu7/iEzpstYazIgjXL6hTx7FioKJsfrpp5cH/vuz0wgNvY0ZbORejByGV0IkHlORCi@3V87L9AG7UvMzFXuWco2ZdXwLCLGWm0zRLarCLqyYI0jhHCmkp91IRZLgTdMF1E5wfn1azAMgC@bOOnWkRJHRmuL@ADO/pMYUbAoex6b9ragpKsJwd2ImddfwB "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 123 bytes

```
¹©Æ½Ø.;µU×_ƭ/;²®_$÷2ị$}ʋ¥⁸;+®Æ½W¤:/$$µƬṪ€F¹;Ḋ$LḂ$?ṭ@ṫ-ṚZæ.ʋ¥ƒØ.,U¤-ịWµ1ịżU×®W¤Ɗ$æ.0ị$ṭµ³’H»3¤¡
ÆRŒPP€ḟ2ḤÇ€ẎḢ€+€Ø-HÆfṀ€<ẠʋƇ‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xT8JQFIV3f8fbsCCwWROZCIMDISEkLEw6GP6Ag0lhaBOaOLBYXVRSTEDooGl8D2Q5N7yBf3H7R563w809JznnfPe34/GDczBYUYgDJVUfeZ@eR3Zb8/GNbKTot8H7WD2eYiyLifYryMroAOllTSnkdsNmXUw3bRif9UzdsJ6qazbbFpsvj83rkD6rZdnOZf68j9STvQHyurzjn8CQyZidKcldlCjpIsdPEbx0sG8ixccZhb3jvNsVDOu3BuuUolLvnlgvRFTkKPE6FN6xCcRc8e79FNuoCBJHEZuFc/XmPw)

This is a relatively efficient but long Jelly answer that uses the continued fractions method to solve the fundamental solution for the Pell equations for \$2×\$ each k-smooth square-free number, finds \$\max(3, \frac{k+1}{2})\$ solutions for each and then checks whether \$\frac{x-1}{2}, \frac{x+1}{2}\$ are smooth for each solution. This is Lehmer’s method, as described in [the question’s Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St%C3%B8rmer%27s_theorem).

A full program that takes a single argument, \$k\$ and returns a list of lists of pairs. The code above doesn’t sort the final output, but the TIO link does.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
³!²R‘Ė
ÇÆFḢ€€€’<³FȦ$€Tị¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZsVDm4IeNcw4Mo3rcPvhNreHOxY9aloDRQ0zbQ5tdjuxTAXICXm4u/vQov///5sCAA)

This takes a long time for 7, but it computes much faster if you remove the squaring of the factorial: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZsWgo3sStA/P0OM63H64ze3hjkWPmtZAUcNMm0Ob3U4sUwFyQh7u7j606P///@YA)

**Explanation:**

```
³!²R‘Ė                Generates a list like [[1,2],[2,3],...]
³!²                  Take the square of the factorial of the input
   R                 Range 1 through through the above number.
    ‘Ė               Decrement and enumerate, yielding desired list


ÇÆFḢ€€€’<³FȦ$€Tị¢  
Ç                    Get the list of pairs  
 ÆF                  Get the prime factors of each number
   Ḣ€€€              Get the base of each
       ’<³           Is each base less than or equal to the input?
          FȦ$€       Check that all bases of a pair fit the above.
              T      Get a list of the truthy indexes
               ị¢    Index into the original list of pairs
                     Implicit output
```

-3 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllen

Comment: I don't read Jelly, can you give an explanation on how this works?

Comment: I don't think this works - isn't `(8,9)` a 3-smooth pair since \$8=2^3\$ and \$9=3^2\$?

Comment: I'm not sure it is though. What makes you think that will hold?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Naive optimism and the fact for all examples I've seen (admittedly not many), the largest pair is less than `k!` (except for 3, which has a small factorial because it is a small number).

Comment: More upper bounds: [A117581](https://oeis.org/A117581)

Comment: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256067456 has a proof of a weak upper bound on the product of the largest pair, but I believe yours is tighter - e.g. at `[2,3,5,7,...,41]` theirs would bound \$(v,w)\$ to have \$v\times w<10^{10^{9925}}\$ while your bound is equivalent to one of \$(41!^2-1)\times(41!^2)\$ which is roughly \$10^{199}\$ (yes the value is below this, but will it always be?)

Comment: @Arnauld that does not help, since they certainly fit within the bound used here.

Comment: `³!²R‘Ė` would save 2, and `ÆfQ€€` would save 1.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Added explanation.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I may be misunderstanding this, in the paper it says that there is an upper bound of the number of pairs of \$3^{2t+1}\$, whereas in my program there is an upper bound of \$t!^2\$ which will be larger for any given \$t\$, right? I haven't yet taken a course that deals with math at this level, so please correct me if I got anything wrong.

Comment: The upper bound you're using is on the maximum number used in a pair, not on the number of pairs (you can't implement an upper bound on the number of pairs in this way as you wont know when to stop looking!) See theorem 7 for an upper bound on the product of the largest pair.

Comment: ...if the factorial were enough in all cases >2 then `³‘!R‘Ė` would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 241 bytes

uses Pell equations

```
(s=#;v@a_:=Max[#&@@@#&/@FactorInteger@a]<=s;Select[{#-1,#+1}/2&/@(t={};k=y=1;While[k<=Max[3,(s+1)/2],If[IntegerQ[x=Sqrt[1+2y^2#]],t~AppendTo~x;k++];y++];t),v@#&]&/@Join[{1},Select[Range[3,Times@@Prime@Range@PrimePi@s],SquareFreeQ@#&&v@#&]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5Ra4MwFIX/yiAgSjIkjr0sDdy9FDoYtLOwh5CN4O6sWLVNsqKI/esuc30593A4fPc0xh@wMb4qzFzKOXaSiAuYzyf5anpFIgAgUQprU/jOblqPJVoweiWdyPGIhVcjueeMUD6lWSjGXo6TqOUguXg/VEdU9WpBPbDYUZ6kmWabb3Uj7VQv87P1itNs@MiI1sxfn08nbL/23bUXNaVaDH/iE3YJS3R48dJVrRr5xG4D3kxbYuDvqwYdwNaGC0v477cVOM3y84@xuLaIu8CJFphOojlUWn8HpXrU8/wL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + sympy, 116 bytes

```python
import sympy
def f(k):x=[i for i in range(2,4**k)if max(sympy.factorint(i))<=k];return[(y,y+1)for y in x if y+1in x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczLCsIwEIXhvU8xy0wtghcQ1D5J6SJoRoeQC2OEzNPHprvDge/PWj4pnlvjkJMU@GrIuns5AjIeb3WaGSgJMHAEsfHtzGm8DINHJgi2mg0cyD5LEo7FMOJj8stdXPlJnI2Ouj9iT2hPVFjd@vS5tLwRMlfE9gc)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + sympy, 111 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
def f(k):
 b=1
 for i in range(2,4**k):
  x=max(factorint(i))<=k
  if x&b:print(i-1,i)
  b=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnBDsIgDADQO1/Rk6FkHqYmJot8DOiqzQIlHQf4elz0@l7p9SP5OgapJNh7Kh04FdHqzGslILvhYiD62QCJAgNn0JDfq71MN@d@C82n0CyFZxXlXC0jPvx2BBO0U1zKX8/zxHho9G2QveP4Ag)

Two variations on my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185498/42248) but in Python 3. They both define a function which accepts an argument `k`. The first returns a list of tuples of the pairs that meet the criteria. The second prints them to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
f!>#QsPMTCtBS^4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P03RTjmwOMA3xLnEKTjO5P9/cwA)

Uses [Nick Kennedy's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185498/41020) that no output number will be larger than `4^k`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
°LʒfàI>‹}Xšü‚ʒ¥`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//8KwTMqSZsOgST7igLl9WMWhw7zigJrKksKlYP//Mw) (extremely inefficient, so times out for \$n\gt3\$..). [Here a slightly faster alternative](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//@KChCpMypJmw6BJPuKAuX1YxaHDvOKAmsqSwqVg//83), although still pretty slow..

**Explanation:**

```python
°                # Take 10 to the power of the (implicit) input
 L               # Create a list in the range [1, 10^input]
  ʒ              # Filter this list by:
   fà            #  Get the maximum prime factor
     I>‹         #  And check if it's smaller than or equal to the input
        }Xš      # After the filter: prepend 1 again
           ü‚    # Create pairs
             ʒ   # And filter these pairs by:
              ¥` #  Where the forward difference / delta is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Θ",²aÇu,á‼⌐çLB
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=e9222cfd6180752ca013a9874c42&i=7&a=1)

This is not the shortest possible program, but it begins producing output as soon as matching pairs are found.  It does terminate *eventually*, but output is produced as it's found.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 89+8 = 97 bytes

Uses the `-rprime` flag. For each number \$i\$ from 1 to \$4^n\$, map it to `[i, i+1]` if both are \$n\$-smooth, otherwise map it to `false`, then prune all `false` from the list.

```ruby
->n{g=->x{x.prime_division.all?{|b,_|b<=n}};(1..4**n).map{|i|g[i]&&g[i+1]&&[i,i+1]}-[!1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY3RCsIgGEZfpW5GrflDEXTRXA9iQyZt8sOmohYL9dUz6@Z85@o79ineeaL3TDoVJCXdGlYwFpeRP/CFDrWCYZ5vIYqGR9FSldJ1dwI417XawzKYEDFKhn1VFR6OZRk2P0mEbQuz2UxMjt6B1xz7fPlo48uty8T@Q18)